# Rails JS.HAML rendering raw html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have used haml in my project. By adding in the following lines of code to example.js.haml returns `<h1>hello</h1>` instead of **hello**

```
:plain
  document.getElementById('light').append("#{escape_javascript(raw '<h1>hello</h1>')}");
```

Need advice on how to tweek example.js.haml so as to return only hello without the html tags

Comment: try,  `document.getElementById('light').append("#{escape_javascript('<h1>hello</h1>').html_safe}");`

Comment: No it does not work :(

Comment: not `{escape_javascript‌​('<h1>hello</h1>').h‌​tml_safe}` if at all then `{escape_javascript‌​('<h1>hello</h1>'.h‌​tml_safe)}`. but i am not sure if this works either

Comment: or do you mean to really print <h1>...?

Comment: I tried all that . It returns hello with the header tags

Comment: on another note: are you not using jquery?

Comment: No I don't intend to print h1..I would want hello to appear as heading

Comment: Jquery and javascript would return the same result I believe

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
:plain
  $('#light').append("#{escape_javascript('<h1>hello</h1>'.html_safe)}");
```

So problem seems to be somewhere else in your code.

Please show your controller

Comment: def example respond_to do |format| format.js end end

Comment: `respond_to(:js)` would suffice in your case. But is not the cause of your error

Comment: I don't understand why - I hav prototype too but I don't think that may be causing the issue since I'm getting the HTML with tags

Comment: as a last idea (if you have not tried this already). Try to render a parial (with `<h1>test</h1>`)

Comment: I tried using a partial first and when that did not work I switched on to this simple example

Answer (score 0):

This was due to Jquery Conflict.

added jquery.noconflict.js

```
(function() { window.$jq = jQuery.noConflict(); })();
```

and changed example.js.haml

```
:plain
  $jq('#light').append("#{escape_javascript('<h1>hello</h1>'.html_safe)}");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing 'raw' keyword? :)

Comment: Yes - that didn't help

Comment: You are also using `:plain`

Check out docs :
http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html